# What's the simplest way to set up my mail server to detect incoming mail?

Tags: ubuntu, email, postfix

In Github, you can reply directly to the mails that they send you.

Their mail servers will "detect" that you sent it, and then my python script will act accordingly.

I'm looking for a good overview answer or a link to a tutorial that goes through this.

What is this setup called?

Comment: Are you asking how to have your mail server automatically respond to new mail arriving locally, or to respond automatically to new mail arriving somewhere else?

Comment: I have a mail server. I use it to send and receive emails (postfix and dovecot).  When this mail server receives an email (for example: messages@mydomain.com), I want my postfix to catch messages sent to this email.  Then, my python script will act accordingly.  My python script would probably check the messages ID in the subject, and do an API POST request to my API servers.

Comment: I'm just looking for the best practice to implement something like this.  When Github sends you a message, you can "reply directly to this email", and their mail server catches it, inserts the message into the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using alias | piping.  This seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

For simple automated responses, Dennis' suggestion is sound.  The `vacation` program is also an ancient, honourable and extensively-tested piece of software to build simple autoresponses around, and it has all the necessary tests to avoid autoresponder storms (where two autoresponders start talking to each other, very very fast, and fill up your email spool).

For something more sophisticated, which you seem to be alluding to, where multiple emails are related to each other, something like [RT](http://www.bestpractical.com/rt) might be a good place to start: emails to particular recipients are ducted into RT, and the first in the chain creates an autoresponse with a custom Subject: line, and as long as anyone who replies to that email preserves the RT token in the subject line, future replies will end up in the right thread inside the RT database.

Answer (score 1):

Postfix can do what you want, by creating custom transports. Make this email address an alias to an address on a nonexistent domain, and define your script as transport for this domain. If you also want to receive the mail yourself, make it an alias to yourself and that nonexistent domain. I used this trick to send mails to an autoreply script when employees are on holiday.

Comment: Is there a step-by-step tutorial on this?

Comment: Can't think of any. Just read [transport(5)](http://linux.die.net/man/5/transport) and [master(5)](http://linux.die.net/man/5/master) and go from there :)

Comment: Why do I need a "Nonexistent" domain? what does that mean?

Comment: You need to use a separate domain, as transports are easiest done per domain. Why waste a real domain on it when something like alex.automates.mail works too as domain?